# Uipath orchestrator Api- redirect uri

Tags: java, typescript, api, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Currently I am using UiPath orchestrator API to implement sign in with UiPath action. All my implementation is based on this [link](http://dealetech.com/the-definitive-guide-to-uipath-cloud-orchestrator-2019-09-rest-api-authentication/). So first I connect my application with UIPath and do an HTTP call to get my authorization code. The problem, for now, is that the redirect_uri should be my application URI in order to return back to me the code. But when I tried to change the redirect URI it responds with mismatch redirect_uri. I searched on the google&uipath forum but there is not any proper answer regarding this question.

As far as I searched, UiPath Cloud has changed their authentication from basic to oAuth. Their [official documentation](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/consuming-cloud-api) does not provide any information on how can I authorize my application to use their API therefore also to authorize redirect_uri.

If I am not being clear about my issue, all I want is to find documentation that explains me step by step integration of UiPath Orchestrator onCloud, like for example [slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack).

Comment: Can you please post any error messages you might be receiving?

Comment: Yes, this is it: https://cloud.uipath.com/portal_/unhandlederror?client_id=8DEv1AMNXczW3y4U15LL3jYf62jK93n5&connection=&lang=en-GB%2Cen-US%3Bq%3D0.9%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.8&error=unauthorized_client&error_description=Callback%20URL%20mismatch.%20http%3A%2F%2Fdev.dev.wirking%3A9010%2Foauth%2Fcallback%20is%20not%20in%20the%20list%20of%20allowed%20callback%20URLs&tracking=9edf9b40dc88fdded699